# How to dismiss popup from popup controller using popupdialogue?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, popup

I am using 'PopupDialog' to display popup. My question is how to dismiss a popup on click of submit custom button in popup.

Popup is in ViewController. and Popupview controller name is PopUPController.

So I want to dismiss a popup from PopUPController.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using navigationController do this:-

```
_= self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

This will navigate to previous viewcontroller.

If it is presented then use this one:-

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: No I am not using navigation Controller.otherwise it is simple

Comment: Is it presented ?

Answer (score 0):

Use dismiss method to dismiss `PopupDialog`

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
```